# Will the component re-render using useStore in react-redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux

If I use the useStore hook in a component, will the component re-render every time the state tree changes in the store? I'd like to use this to access an updated version of the store inside of a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you change the data using the set Method of created hook. It changes the state variables.

example-

```js
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Explanation: 
**When you click the button it will call the setCount() method which will change the count (state variable) value and our component is using that value(subscribed to state change). It will trigger the render() method.**
More details can be followed here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: I'm talking about the useStore function from the react-redux library, not the useState function from the react library.

Comment: @nratter Sorry, I might have misread that one. Usually, if state changes, any component that has subscribed to the state should re-render to reflect the change. To capture the change you might use logic inside the proper lifecycle method. Thanks.